# Base data structure for Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

**`List<T>`** uses **`Array`** as base data structure.

I searched for **`Dictionary`**'s base data structure but couldn't find the answer.

Will someone please tell me which data structure or set of data structures are used as **`base`** data structure for **Dictionary** ?

Comment: Why you interested for it? It is just implementation detail.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan nothing special, just for curiosity, from this week i started to search about the base data structures used frequently in collections of .net framework

Comment: @HamletHakobyan it's more than a year since i started my professional career and still i don't know about all of them, it's a shame as a developer i guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Dictionary uses a `HashTable` internally:

> The `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` generic class provides a mapping from a set of keys to a set of values. Each addition to the dictionary consists of a value and its associated key. Retrieving a value by using its key is very fast, close to O(1), because the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class is implemented as a **hash table.**